# max connected Endpoints with Nearby-Connections

Tags: android, google-nearby

I created an app with the google-nearby connections API with the strategie cluster. 
On googles developer page they explained, that the cluster strategie is for an  M-to-N topology. But it seems that the max client count is 6 endpoints. If a 7th endoint tries to connect, on the advertiser the bluetooth crashes.
Regarding to wikipedia the max connected client count in a piconet (bluetooth master/slave) should be seven. 
Any tips how I can connect more than 6 devices to one advertiser? I can't use the star topology because these one uses wireless hotspots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phone radios tend to be pretty weak, and even though they theoretically should hit 7, most struggle past 4 connections.

There's an upcoming update to Nearby Connections that will switch devices to a LAN connection if they're on the same network. But if that's not an option, you'll have to make a mesh of devices and route messages between them.

Comment: That means the 1:N topology is currently only for ad hoc hotspot connections available. Or is N anyway only <7?

Comment: Hotspots can have higher than 7 connections, but it again depends on hardware. Expect around 5~10 max. If a phone fails to upgrade to the hotspot, it will continue using it's Bluetooth connection so you get some small amount of load balancing that way, but if your use-case involves tens or hundreds of phones you really need to build a mesh.

Comment: Can you please write a blog or something describing how to implement the mesh network using nearby connections? It will help a lot. Thanks.